# Calculate descriptive statistics by row using column data from other table

Tags: sql, sas

I have two tables like below

Table 1

```
ID    day start end
21005 3   4004  4012
21005 3   4031  4055
21005 4   4671  4679
21005 4   4689  4792
21005 4   4803  4828
21005 4   4837  4860
21005 4   5301  5424
21005 6   8068  8084
21005 6   8114  8148
21005 7   9239  9256
21005 7   9311  9326
21005 7   9497  9515
21005 7   9535  9574
21005 7   9615  9627
21005 7   9679  9694
21006 3   3738  3752
21006 5   7065  7077
21006 6   8374  8402
21007 1   732   742
21007 1   773   785
21007 1   831   853
21007 1   865   876
21007 1   880   894
...................
```

Table 2

```
ID    day time concentration
21005 1   1    562
...................
21005 2   1    90
...................
21005 3   1    2258
...................
21005 3   4004 1981
21005 3   4005 3077
21005 3   4006 1371
21005 3   4007 1990
21005 3   4008 1869
21005 3   4009 934
21005 3   4010 413
21005 3   4011 2506
21005 3   4012 2948
...................
21005 3   4031 2266
21005 3   4032 4711
21005 3   4033 0
21005 3   4034 12
21005 3   4035 1017
21005 3   4036 1215
21005 3   4037 990
21005 3   4038 3083
21005 3   4039 1391
21005 3   4040 3762
21005 3   4041 1568
21005 3   4042 2907
21005 3   4043 2295
21005 3   4044 939
21005 3   4045 884
21005 3   4046 2067
21005 3   4047 1473
21005 3   4048 1070
21005 3   4049 1403
21005 3   4050 1464
21005 3   4051 1049
21005 3   4052 1513
21005 3   4053 333
21005 3   4054 104
21005 3   4055 1133
...................
```

and I would like to create a summary table using table 1 and table 2 data

summary table

```
ID    day start end  min max  mean    median sum
21005 3   4004  4012 413 3077 1898.78 1981   17089
21005 3   4031  4055 0   4711 1545.96 1391   38649
................................................
```

basically summary table = calculate the min max mean median and sum of concentration using start and end time in table 1, by ID and day. I have no idea about how to do this ...

what I tried:

```
data test;
    merge table2 table1(keep=id day start end);
    by ID day;
    if start<=time <=end;
run;
```

then proc summary by ID and day

but problem is for the same day, there's multiple start and end

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to merge table 2 to table 1 by id and day, then calculate the descriptive stats, but there's multiple start and end for same day

Comment: Please show the code you have tried

Comment: first sort table 1 and table 2 by ID and day then data test;
 merge table2 table1(keep=id day start end);
 by ID day;
 if start<=time <=end;
run;

adter that I was trying to use the start and end to determine if time is between start and end,  but problem is there's multiple start and end for the same day

Answer (score 0):

Consider an SQL `join` query using `between` range filter on *time*:

```
proc sql;
   create table summary_table as
   select t1.ID, 
          t1.day,
          min(concentration) as min,
          max(concentration) as max,
          mean(concentration) as mean,
          median(concentration) as median,
          sum(concentration) as sum

   from table1 t1
   inner join table2 t2
       on t1.ID = t2.ID and t1.day = t2.day

   where t2.time between t1.start and t2.end
   group by t1.ID, 
            t1.day;
quit;
```